# import data from another table with same id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, import

User (id, name, surname,cod)

UserNew (uid, uname, usurname, ucod)

The first table has data the second no.

I have to copy the data of the User table in the UserNew table.

I've tried with a insert query but uid (primary key) value changes.

How can i do to mantaince the same values?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `uid` of the `UserNew` table is an identity (autoincrement) column. So you could issue a `SET IDENTITY_INSERT UserNew ON` statement, then insert the data (including the correct id) and then issue a `SET IDENTITY_INSERT UserNew OFF`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(SQL.80).aspx